# Issues remoting to perfmon

Tags: performance, statistics, perfmon

Hey all, 
I'm having trouble with PerfMon on one system out of fifteen in a development environment. Accessing it from the local machine is fine but connecting to it remotely throws a "Cannot connect" error.

Each machine is running Win 2003, is connected to the same domain and I have admin rights to all.

There were some services set to disabled which are normally enabled by default so I've set these to match the other machines on the network - still have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Cheers

**Update**

Ok - I found it was the remote registry service not running correctly causing the above error; Once that was enabled Perfmon is now telling me "No such interface supported".

If I connect through Computer Management, it fails the first time, but the second attempt is successful. Connecting through perfmon fails everytime.

Comment: and that is programming related how?

Comment: good point - I'm trying to connect to performance counters through WMI, but can't even get in via Perfmon. Feel free to move the topic if you don't think it's related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed - for anyone that runs into this issue, hopefully this can help you..

Enabling Remote Registry fixed my first problem.

The second issue, "No such interface supported" turned out to be permissions issues within the registry. Apparently the machine had some pretty obscure permissions set to specific registry keys a long time ago, which are now irrelevant.

Resetting permissions with secedit fixed it up -

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose
```

Perfmon counters are now accessible remotely.

Answer (score 5):

We encountered the second issue - "No such interface supported" when attempting to "Connect to another computer" in Performance monitor.

All the rules and services are running.

We found the following:

- If the user was added to the local admin group, they were able to connect to another computer (irrespective of belonging to the Performance Monitor group).
- If the user was not a local admin and in the performance monitor group - we were unable to connect to another computer via the "Connect to another computer" context menu.

  - **But we were able to add the performance counters**. In Performance monitor when you add a counter there is an option to "Select counters from computer". We were able to connect to the counters on the remote machine this way. Also note that if you are planning on data collecting, you would need to set the correct credentials (by default it appears to run under a local system user).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my case as follows:

- Add Firewall rule Performance Logs and Alerts from the predefined rule list.
- From client, run the Performance Monitor as the remote user
  Eg: `runas /user:remote_machine\username "mmc perfmon.msc"`

Of course, the user  must be at least in the user groups "Performance Log users" or "Performance Monitor Users".

Answer (score 0):

The reason why perfmon.exe do not want to connect to the remote server is, it wants to connect to the Perf Monitor **and** the Perf Logs (Data collections).

So you have to add the user account to **also the Log User group** and of course to the Monitor Users.

[image]

you don't need to be local admin on the remote server!